# Cannot craft a forge 1.12 modded item

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I coded a forge minecraft 1.12 mod but when trying ingame to craft items, it doesn't work.

Here is the JSON file :

```
{
    "type": "crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        "ccc",
        " / ",
        " / "
    ],
    "key": {
        "c": {
            "item": "cocoricomod:poliro_ingot",
        },
        "/": {
            "item": "minecraft:stick",
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "cocoricomod:poliro_pickaxe",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Do you have any error output you can include in the question?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the recipe does not load is because the JSON parser used by Minecraft does not support trailing commas in JSON objects. It might also be required to provide the full type, which in your case would be `minecraft:crafting_shaped`.
Fixing both issues, this is the result:

```json
{
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        "ccc",
        " / ",
        " / "
    ],
    "key": {
        "c": {
            "item": "cocoricomod:poliro_ingot"
        },
        "/": {
            "item": "minecraft:stick"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "cocoricomod:poliro_pickaxe",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Full documentation on Forge recipes can he found [here](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities/recipes/).

Comment: Good to hear. You should mark this answer as accepted if this solved your problem. Enjoy the Minecraft modding!